# Is there a module to conditionally set a fields value depending another field?

Tags: 7, entities

is there a module that can set a value of a field which depends on the value of another field first? I know i can do it via js, but was wondering if something was out there already. conditional field module doesnt work in my case as it dosent set the value depending on the result of another.

example: I am creating a basic page and I have a select box field with the following: white/black/red. when i select red, i want the body to be filled in with 'yes' and if its black i want the body to be filled in with 'no'.

Comment: "You may draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields" - **how** this does not work for you?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention im talking about the content creation page.

Comment: No there isn't a module that can arbitrarily set the value of any field based on the contents of another inside an arbitrary, undefined context. Such a thing would be too difficult to implement, and impossible to use effectively. If you need something that complex it's time to pull out the custom modules :)

Comment: And? It works for me on nodes all right. What's your problem again? You want to narrow choices in select Y based on what got selected in field Z? Or what?

Comment: when something is selected in field Y it should auto input a string into field Z. maybe a quick js snippet would just do it.

Comment: I don't think there is a module for that. Would be damn complicated, and to use it you would need write scripts just as complicated as simple jQuery.

Comment: check this module, maybe it will help https://drupal.org/project/fieldactions

Comment: @duckx Did you find an alternate? I want to do similar thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to check on the fields you set as dependant and dependee! In your case the body field should be the dependant and the selection field should be dependee.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

No other module available apart from conditional field, you need to create your own module with hook form_alter() and use some code like

```
<?php
function wishlist_status_form($form_state) {
$form['status'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Status',
    '#suffix' => '<div id="my-wrapper"></div>',
  );

$form['ajax-submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'wishlist_status_change',
        'wrapper' => 'my-wrapper',
    ),
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );
return $form;
}

function wishlist_status_change($form, $form_state) {
    dpm($form_state, 'state callback');
    return 'test';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be difficult to change the value of a field without some coding. But it if you just want to store the value based on the value of some other field you should take a look at [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module and create 2 rules.

- **Event:** After saving new content.
- **Condition:**

  1. Entity has field. Parameter: Entity: `[node]`, Field: field_colours (*Or whatever your field is called.*)
  2. Data comparison. Parameter: Data to compare: `[node:field-colours]`, Data value: Red
- **Actions:** Set a data value. Parameter: Data: `[node:field-body]`, Value: Yes

You can create a similar rule for 'black'.